# EggOn Implemention In Android

Tags: android, android-testing

I am developing an Android Application in which i need to tun test cases.After searching a lot,I found eggon compatible in which normal user will run script and test cases will be resolved.I downloaded the eggon apk hosted on their official website and tried to run that apk to see how actually eggon works.I downloaded the eggon windows exe file through which communication is to be done.
But issue is that Eggon apk is asking for license key.So if anyone has integrated Eggon in Android Application, then can he guide me how to make the eggon apk.
My question is How the EggPlant is able to automate the test on OS level( can open contacts, phone application through scripts)?

Note: This will be an in-House enterprise application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eggOn is a client-server automation suite that works over a network connection. The idea is that you have a server (your PC int his case) and a client (your mobile device), you then write the test scripts and deploy and run them on the mobile device automatically.

To do this you need, both the [EggPlant Functional](http://www.testplant.com/dlds/eggplant-functional/) program installed on your PC and the [eggOn mobile app](http://www.testplant.com/dlds/eggplant-mobile-eggon/) installed on your mobile device.

You will then write scripts in the eggPlant functional script editor, connect over the network to your mobile device (I think you can also do this via USB cable and forgo the network connection), deploy your script and let it control and test your mobile application.

In answer to you your question **"How the EggPlant is able to automate the test on OS level( can open contacts, phone application through scripts)?"**

It sends commands to the eggOn mobile application which can control OS level actions, such as emulate keystrokes and touchscreen events. Read [the documentation for this](http://docs.testplant.com/?q=content/device-control-0) for more information.

Comment: Basically Isn't the server app should be on the mobile